# crt2.o file not recognized: file format not recognized

Tags: c, windows, mingw

`crt2.o file not recognized: file format not recognized`

Не могу скомпилировать программу в MimGw, язык Си. При этом бинарники `gcc -c main.c` компилируются без проблем, но при их линковке, или если тот же файл скомпилировать `gcc -o main main.c` то сразу выскакивает ошибка приведенная выше. В чем проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: Ошибка-то не приведена. Ни выше, ни ниже.

Comment: ошибка в заголовке, сам заголовок - это ошибка, которая выскакивает

Comment: для тех, кто все ещё не понял, добавил ее еще раз в самом тексте вопроса

Comment: Я просто оставлю это здесь: http://bonanza-event.ru/sites/bonanza-event.ru/files/show-programms/element_7_how_to_do_mime_face_makeup_-see-here.jpg

Comment: А где исходники?

Comment: Установили что-то не то (библиотеки компилятора (crt2.o это один из startup файлов) не для исполнения в системе, на которой собираете). Вот штатный линкер и ругается.

Comment: Eanmos - он даже элементарный hello world не компилирует.

Comment: Установлен только один компилятор?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно gcc более многословен, потому старайтесь более полно приводить его выхлоп, чтобы нам не приходилось заниматься телепатией.

Когда вы используете опцию -о без -с, то на выходе получается не объектник для линковки, а готовый бинарник для запуска. И линкер совершенно не понимает, что с этим делать.

Comment: 1) Никакой телепатии - это все, что выводит компилятор. 2) Я не идиот и знаю что за опции -o -c и как ими пользоваться, и в вопросе четко написано, что при компилировании бинарника все ок, а вот при линковке и компилировании с -o вылазит приведенная ошибка. PS читайте внимательнее вопрос на который собрались отвечать

Comment: Да тут все не идиоты. А можно скриншот вместе с опциями запуска?

Comment: Сериншот пока не получится (я несколько дней не буду дома) но: запускается через make, все бинарники собираются с флагом wall и указанием стандарта gnu99, все компилируется хорошо, пока дело не доходит до линковки - тогда выскакивает ошибка, приведенная выше, и, собственно все. Это что касается проги, которую мне нужно скомпилировать. Но, опять таки, как я уже писал, элементарныц helloworld тоже отказывается компилироваться (если только не компилируется бинарник).

Comment: Пока можно почитать астрал: возможно какие-то проблемы, связанные с переменными окружения и запуском чего-то не того, что надо.

Comment: Астрал? Ну ок, экстрасенс, что же ты тогда скажешь видя скрин? https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxM92zv79qxrU0E4T1dhbmc2Ym8

Comment: Вижу, что вы должны мне $100 за то, что закапали мне мыло в глаза. А теперь вопрос: зачем вам цигвин?

Comment: a что это такое?

Comment: А вот эта зелено-желтая часть в приглашении - это что?

Comment: А вообще, зачем вы занимаетесь извращением через виртуалочку, когда на основную систему тоже можно поставить мингв и компилировать виндовые бинарники через удобное и привычное окружение? Лично я так свои бинарники и компиляю.

Comment: 1) не могу понять про какую "зелено-желтую часть" ты говоришь. 2) нет - мне нужно так

Comment: если ты хочешь сказать, что у меня Cygwin - то нет, это MinGW и MSYS

Comment: Ну, тогда я ошибся. Могу посоветовать сменить окружение: к примеру, скачать полный бандл последнего Qt, к нему в комплекте идет рабочее окружение мингв, меняете переменные окружения на него и можно попробовать снова. А вот с MSYS лично у меня тоже ничего не получилось.

Comment: Эту проблему я уже давно решил полной переустановкой и расширенной установкой дополнений - какое из них нужное - хрен его знает, я не в курсе, просто интересно знать с чем это все таки связано.

Comment: Подозреваю, что файл мог побиться